# How to rsync symlinks and their referents but preserving the links

Tags: rsync, symlink

I have the following filestructure in my src directory:

```
en/
en/a/
en/a/file1 -> ../../en/mp3/file1-longer-name-a
en/a/file2 -> ../../en/mp3/file2-longer-name-a
en/mp3/file1-longer-name-a
en/mp3/file1-longer-name-b
en/mp3/file2-longer-name-a
en/mp3/file3-longer-name-a
```

I am interested to copy all the files under en/a/ to the destination, preserving symlinks, and also include the referent files (which BTW are all within en/) but not other files under en/mp3/ if they are not referred by any symlinks I am transferring.

I'm using the following command, that does the obvious part of the job:

```
rsync -avRz "${SRC}./en/a" "${DST}"
```

this transfers the following files:

```
en/
en/a/
en/a/file1 -> ../../en/mp3/file1-longer-name-a
en/a/file2 -> ../../en/mp3/file2-longer-name-a
```

and I hope you'll help me to tweak the rsync args so that the following files will be transferred too:

```
en/mp3/file1-longer-name-a
en/mp3/file2-longer-name-a
```

is there a way to achieve this without needing to write an algorythm to loop over the softlinks under en/a/ and transfer the files they point to one-by-one?

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but you might have a look at rsync's `--copy-links` or `-L` flag. Instead of copying the symlinks it resolves them and copies the files. But that's not a good idea if you've got many links to one file.

Comment: I already tried that, but I need the symlinks to stay symlinks in the en/a/ directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `find` in combination with rsync's `--files-from` parameter:

```
find "${SRC}./en/a" -type l -exec readlink {} ';'|sort|uniq|rsync -avRz --files-from=- "${SRC}" "${DST}"
```

- `find` lists all symlinks in the en/ folder and executes readlink on each of them.
- then we sort the list and filter out duplicates (with `sort` and `uniq`)
- and rsync gets the `--files-from` param set to `-` to read the files it should sync from stdin

Comment: OK, it worked, the only thing I had to change was: `rsync -avRz --files-from=- "${SRC}" "${DST}"` (i.e: removed "./en/a", because the files that find gave me already had that)

Comment: Fixed the answer.